# omniauth-facebook Gem: omniauth.auth sometimes has nil provider and uid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

My application is authenticating users with the [omniauth-facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) gem version 1.6.0. It seems that sometimes within the `facebook` action in the `OmniauthCallbacksController`, the `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` hash will have nil values for `provider` and `uid`.

I would appreciate any insight into why this would happen. Here's the relevant code from my omniauth config initializer

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'],
     {:scope => 'email, offline_access', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}}}
```

Comment: not enough info to go on...

Comment: @TarynEast What else would you like to see?

Comment: anything you've got. Where are you using facebook auth? what are the steps to reliably reproduce the error? what kind of users does this happen for (and not)? What research have you done on this topic and why were the results unsatisfactory... what code is relevant? what do you get in your logfiles? etc etc